# Android how to set time zone through application

Tags: android, timezone

Android provides a permission called "SET_TIME_ZONE" with OS permission level "dangerous". Does anyone know that given an application with this permission, how can the app set the time zone ?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For Setting of the Time Zone Programetically you need to use the Date Class. 
See its Reference Documents [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html).

You need to use the `setTimeZone()` method of `SimpleDateFormat` Class.

Following is sample code for settings Time Zone of according to America

```
// First Create Object of Calendar Class
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();        
// Now Set the Date using DateFormat Class
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss z"); 
// Finally Set the time zone using SimpleDateFormat Class's setTimeZone() Method
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
```

Comment: In your opinion, should the code work if the application does not have SET_TIME_ZONE permission ?

Comment: @Jake: It must "work". All it does is setting the `TimeZone` for an object of yours. That's like saying `int a=43`, nothing what the OS cares about. The global setting is what you need permissions for, see the other answer.

Comment: This answer shows how to set the timezone on an SimpleDateFormat instance, not the system.  See Dheeraj's answer.

Comment: -1 because this answer is actually not an answer to the question and because it is not possible to set the TimeZone via Date-class.

Answer (score 16):

If your objective is to change the system's default time zone, then use [setTimeZone()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setTimeZone%28java.lang.String%29) of AlarmManager.

Answer (score 6):

You can set the TimeZone in multiple ways:

1. You can use [TimeZone.setDefault()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault%28java.util.TimeZone%29) which will change the TimeZone for the current process only. But as noted in the docs, this is not garanteed to last for the whole application lifecycle.
2. You can use [setTimeZone()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setTimeZone%28java.lang.String%29) of [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to change the TimeZone of the whole device. But you need the "SET_TIME_ZONE"-permission for that.

If you think 1. is to dangerous and you don't have the permission for 2. your best approach is to get every Date from [Calendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) and set the TimeZone on your Calendar-instance via [setTimeZone()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#setTimeZone%28java.util.TimeZone%29).

Comment: It's a shame the first solution is not guaranteed to work for 100%. Do you have more information in which cases `TimeZone.setDefault()` gets invalidated or overwritten? The documentation only states "This value may be cleared or overwritten at any time" but the documentation does not clarify in more details when this is going to happen and why.

Comment: @StefanArn Sorry, I don't have any information present. But I suspect it may be modified by the system, if the device is configured to set the date and timezone by network or similar sources (i.e. GPS).