# Set default time zone to use for an android application

Tags: android

I'm developing an application for android that has to list activities with its date and time. I would like to ignore the time zone of the device and show always the time in timezone +02:00.

The application is for Spain, but If someone from UK that is in another time zone use the application I want that the time for activities appear in local spanish time.

The date is in UTC format, using Calendar.getTime().toLocaleString(), the time appers in local time zone of device.

I would like to know if the is a way to set a default time zone that has to use my application, and when I invoke Calendar.getTime().toLocaleString() method get the time always in local time zone +2 despite of the device timezone

Answer (score 9):

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+3"));
```

This sets the default timezone. Subsequent calls to `Calendar.getInstance()` always return as if the device was in that timezone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to  set the time zone of your calendar.
This can be done like this :

```
Calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone timezone);
```

And then your calendar will work with a different time zone.

If you want to change the system time zone this can be done by using `setTimeZone()` of AlarmManager.

When doing that the manifest has to contain the right permission, which is

> android.permission.SET_TIME

Link to  [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setTimeZone%28java.lang.String%29)

And there is some other solution i found [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755625/android-how-to-set-time-zone-through-application), check it out.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't explained well, what I want is a way to set a default time zone for my application. When I invoke Calendar.getTime().toLocaleString() I want to get always the time in timezone +2 despite of the local time zone of the device. I want to avoid to make calendar.setTimeZone every time I print a time in user screen.

Comment: But if I'm not wrong I have tot set Calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone timezone); every time I has to display a time. Then I don't like the option of change system timezone because I will change device time, every time that my application lost focus I will have to retore system time zone. I'm looking for a way to set the default time zone only for my aplication, and I would like to avoid to invoke Calendar.setTimeZone(Timezone) every time I has to disply a time. Thanks

Comment: Try it, and then you'll know if you're wrong or not. but edited with a link to another solution.

Comment: Thanks for your solutions, I have tried but I have to set the Timezone everytime I want to display a time. What I'm looking for is a way to do something like as MyApplicationSetting.setTimeZone("Madrid"); set the timezone only one time, and then with SimpleDataFormat.Format(MyDate) time be displayed in time zone of Spain despite of the device time zone.

Comment: @MarcCals did you ever find the answer to your question? I am also currently looking for this kind of implementation for setting the timezone.

Comment: Hi @Hilfritz!, No I didn't find any answer.