# Python vs Java UTC?

Tags: java, android, python, time, utc

I've been having some problems with a time-based application I'm developing, which uses Java in the Android client side and Python in the server side. I encountered a discrepancy of -3 hours (which is exactly the timezone from the Android device) in the times reported by Java and Python, even though in both sides I'm getting the time in a way that (according to SO and other sites) returns a UTC time.
In my client, I'm using

```
Date utcNow = new Date()
```

and in the server, i use

```
datetime.datetime.now()
```

Yet, when run at the same time, they yield `2013-09-09 11:52:16` and `2013-09-09 14:52:16`, respectively. I suspect the issue is on Java side, since running `date` in the server returns the same value as Python (obviously), with the timezone UTC, and the same command in the Android device returns a BRT (GMT-3) time.

While searching for timezone adjustment on both languages, all answers claimed that the methods above would return a UTC date, yet this difference is clearly visible.

How can I convert the Android device's time to UTC?

Right now I'm using a really ugly (and extremely deprecated) solution: `utcNow.setHours(utcNoe.getHours()+3)`

**EDIT:** Side note: From Jon's answer, I noticed Java's `Date` objects are equivalent to Python's naive `datetime` objects.

Comment: How *exactly* are you determining the value of each expression? After all, a `Date` isn't a `String`... if you call `Date.toString()` that will show you the value *in the system local time zone* but that isn't information which is in the `Date` value itself.

Comment: The issue is creating the `Date`s in client side. This is more a conceptual problem than a programming language problem. Imagine the server is configured with UTC 0 and I use a client from Peru (where I live) with UTC -5 and send a request to the server with a `Date` created using my time zone.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: No, it's really not. A `Date` doesn't *have* a time zone. It's just an instant in time.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm using a SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: @Kroltan: And are you specifying the time zone for that `SimpleDateFormat`? If not, that's the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I strongly suspect the problem is in the code you haven't shown us - when you convert the `Date` to a `String` in Java via `SimpleDateFormat`.

A `Date` itself is just an instant in time, with no time zone or calendar system associated with it. In order to convert it to a string, both need to be applied - and the default time zone in a `SimpleDateFormat` is the system local time zone.

If you just change your code to:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
                                               Locale.US);
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
String dateText = format.format(date);
```

then I suspect your problems will go away. Note that this is *not* part of the `Date` information itself. (It's really important to understand that.)

Also note that the date/time API in Java is pretty horrible. If you're able to use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) instead, you're likely to have a better time of it. (It would be overkill if all you need is a timestamp, but if you have any actual date/time work to do, you should definitely consider it.)

Comment: I'm not on my work computer right now, so I can't test it, but this answer is really promising, I was just creating a `SimpleDateFormat` with a string format. It's weird to have timezones controlled by a format, not the date/time information itself. Indeed I only need to transmit a timestamp to the server once, to receive a list of new content, so Joda would just boost my APK size.

Comment: @Kroltan: It's not particularly weird - there are various different kinds of value that you may want, which is why Joda Time has `Instant`, `LocalDateTime`, `LocalDate`, `LocalTime`, `DateTime` etc.

Comment: As Jon Skeet suggests, [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) is the way to go. To get a UTC date-time object: `DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.UTC )`. Unlike a java.util.Date, a Joda-Time [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) object does have an assigned [time zone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Answer (score 1):

This has been asked many times before. Have a look at [Set Time Zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755625/android-how-to-set-time-zone-through-application). You can also use this approach to change the timezone.

--- EDIT
If you want to transmit your timezone as a string, you should transmit it using [ISO_8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) that way you can adjust the time on your server.

Comment: The ISO 8601 standard is very useful. Unlike many standards, it is practical and well thought-out. Full of good stuff like an official definition of week-of-year, and representation of spans of time. The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) is quite informative.