# Is there a way to change timezone through React Native app?

Tags: timezone, react-native

I am working on a React Native app and wanted the user to be able to change device's timezone. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755625/android-how-to-set-time-zone-through-application) post but it's really old and I was unable to use TimeZone in the component screen itself. I have added 'SET_TIME_ZONE' permission in the Manifest but don't know how I can use it. If there are any libraries or any methods that I am unaware of, please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: @Sankamil, please check this link may help you 

[react-timezone-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-timezone-select)

Comment: @SiddharthPatel thanks for the link! The component will definitely be useful, but I don't think it really allows me to change the device's timezone.